# Rails - Devise - "Your password was set successfully. You are now signed in" - How to disable?

Tags: ruby-on-rails-3, devise

currently with Devise when you set a password the flash notice: "Your password was set successfully. You are now signed in" is displayed.

How can you disable that flash notice?

Thanks

Answer (score 3):

Devise uses flash messages with I18n. To customize your app, the simplest way is to set up your locale file:

```
en:
  devise:
    passwords:
      updated: ""
```

Empty messages won't be shown.

Comment: That works for me but I don't use devise invitable. This message arises when user resets his password. I think that in your case it comes up when user follow invitation link, doesn't it? From your question it's not clear. If so, try change `passwords` to `invitations`. This message from devise invitable, not from devise.